# how to know insert in mysql failed due to duplicate primary key

Tags: mysql

I am inserting records in user_table with user_email as primary key.

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, "insert into user_table(user_full_name, user_email, user_password) values('".$fullnames."','".$emails."','".$passs."')");
```

How to know that insert failed due to duplicate primary key, without quering once again to user_table

Comment: Use [`mysqli_error()`](http://php.net/mysqli_error)

Comment: mysqli_query returns true if insert success and false if failed.  But it does not tells what was the reason for failure of insertion

Comment: [You doing it WRONG!](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: $result is true on successful insertion, and false on failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**mysqli_errno()**, function can help you,

try this

```
if (!$result )
  {
      if(mysqli_errno($con) == 1062){
       echo "duplicate entry";
      }else{
       echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
      }
  }
```

For More error code :https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-messages-server.html

Comment: figured out just before u

Answer (score 1):

I can answer my question myself.

after query

I can check 
    if( mysqli_errno($db) == 1062 )  { 
 
         ""********DUPLICATE PRIMARY KEY*********   
 
 }